# Firebase Auth rules to allow access for both registered users and public - Angular - Ionic

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have two apps using the same Firestore database. One is a backend web app (using Angular)and the other is an frontend app using Ionic.

My back end app will only allow registered users (and logged in users) to access the database. I have setup my Firebase Auth rules to restrict access based on uid. This works perfectly. Here is a rule example:

```
// Allow access to document if user signed in = uid on document
        match /fundraisers/{fundraiser} {
        allow write, read: if  if isOwner(resource.data.uid);
// Reusable function to determine document ownership
    function isOwner(userId) {
        return request.auth.uid == userId
    }
```

But now I want anyone that uses the frontend app (in Ionic) to be able to read and update the fundraiser document. The users using the frontend app do not need to logged in or registered to use the app. Is there an app setting or some variable that I can set in my Ionic app, that I can then pass to the Firebase Auth rules that will allow read and update requests to the document?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to simply pass some parameter from the client to the rules.  That would not be very secure at all, since you can't trust client code to be correct.

It's also not possible to restrict access to only users of your app.  Anyone can try to access your database from anywhere on the internet using the Firestore REST API.

If you want unauthenticated access, your rules will simply need to allow that.  You will not be able to require anything like `request.auth.uid == userId` since unauthenticated users will not have any value for `request.auth`.

Answer (score 0):

This is highly unsecure but what you could do is to define data shape that is allowed to be written into firebase database:

```
{
    "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      "$docId": {
        ".write": true,
        ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['c','i','t','u']) || newData.hasChild('l')",
        "c": { ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 50000" },
        "i": { ".validate": "newData.isNumber()" },
        "l": { 
          "c": { ".validate": "newData.isNumber()" },
          "$other": { ".validate": "newData.isBoolean()" }
        },
        "t": { ".validate": "newData.isNumber()" },
        "u": { ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 50" },
        "$other": { ".validate": false }
      }
    }
  }
```

There is also an option to support "anonymous" login https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth

Which can at the least help track unique IDs of anonymous users and potentially do some firebase functions based checks.

But I agree this is highly insecure.

Comment: I looked into the anonymous login. This seems to be a solution that would meet my requirements (allow read, update: if  request.auth.uid != null;). When someone uses the app, they will be logged in anonymously and be able to update the "fundraisers" document. So unless someone can also log into my database anonymously via another method, my data should be somewhat safe.